# Several Event Types in the Same Topic With Kafka, Quarkus and Avro

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, quarkus, microprofile

I am trying to read an event from a topic using Quarkus. The topic could contain different types of events. All the events use the AVRO format, so I have a schema registry where I can read the releted schema of an event. I use avro-maven-plugin to compile the schema into a Java class.

Suppose we have two types of events with the following schemas:

Event1

```json
{
   "field1": "string"
}
```

Event2

```json
{
   "field2": "string"
}
```

In my application I am interested only on one of them.

```java
 public class Consumer {

    @Incoming("test-in")
    public CompletionStage<Void> read(
        IncomingKafkaRecord<String, Event1> data) {
        System.out.println(data.getKey());
        System.out.println(data.getPayload());
        return data.ack();
    }
}
```

This code print all the events not only the evnts of type `Event1` as I expected.

When I try to get data from the event `data.getField1()` I get a `CastException`.

```java
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to class com.test.Event1 (org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record is in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @1aa7ecca; com.test.Event1 is in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @1144a55a)
```

There is a way to read only some event types from a topic with several event types usign AVRO?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (little bit verbouse) is using `SpecificRecord` as payload type and set      `specific.avro.reader=true` on application configuration file for incoming events.

```java
 public class Consumer {

    @Incoming("test-in")
    public CompletionStage<Void> read(
        IncomingKafkaRecord<String, SpecificRecord> data) {
            String schemaFullName = data.getPayload().getSchema().getFullName();
            if (schemaFullName.equals(Event1.class.getName())) {
                System.out.println(((Event1) data.getPayload()).getField1());
            }
        return data.ack();
    }
}
```

After selecting the event you can cast the `SpecificRecord` to the correct compiled Avro event class.